# Efficient way to prevent UDP port scan

Tags: iptables, udp, port-scanning, blacklist-prevention

I have a Ubuntu server, there are services public in some ports, include TCP and UDP, and trying to protect it against port scanner (TCP and UDP). The TCP scanner block is done by using "recent" module of iptables, which detect and blacklist TCP port scanner. The UDP port scanner way is differ from TCP. AFAIK, UDP scanner method is: sent UDP package to all (UDP) port in target server S, if port P is closed, S will return a ICMP "port-unreachable" error code, the attacker will know that port is closed and the open ports (is there are) is within remain ports. If there is no response from S, attacker with assume that port P is open of filtered by firewall, which cost him long time to distinguish. From this clue, I think about two idea:

- Block ICMP in all port except my service ports. 

- Block any UDP ports except my services port.
I am not expert in attack preventing. Is there some way to block UDP port scan without affect my service ports normal operation?